# Surface Integral of vector field bounded by two spheres

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I have this problem:

A vector field $\vec{F} =\hat R\, \frac{\cos^2 (\phi)}{R^3} \ $ exists in the region between two spherical shells with same origin defined by $R=1$ and $R=2$. Find  $\int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$ and $\int \nabla\cdot\vec{F} \,dV$ ( verify div. theorem)

Note spherical coords. that I use are $(R, \theta, \phi)$

I was able to find it using divergence theorem and got the answer $-14*\pi/3$
but I could not  determine the correct regions and integral limits for $dS$
since $\vec{F}$ has only $\hat R$ as a unit vector I think I can only deal with $dS= R^2 \sin \theta \, d \theta \, d\phi$, but $R$ also changes in my case ! Help please..

Comment: It is cos^2(ϕ)/(R^3)*(unit vector of R)

Comment: please use Latex...

Comment: How can I use it. Sorry I did not know about it

Comment: [A MathJaX tutorial is available here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  I did a first pass at coding it properly, but you may need to edit the question to correct any errors I might have introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec F=\hat r\,\frac{\cos^2(\phi)}{r^3}$.  Then, $\nabla \cdot \vec F=-\frac{2\cos^2(\phi)}{r^4}$.

Using the divergence theorem, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec F\,dV &=\oint_S \vec F \cdot \hat n\,dS\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi }\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{\cos^2(\phi)}{2^3}\,(2^2)-\frac{\cos^2(\phi)}{1^3}\,(1^2)\right)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\frac12 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos^2(\phi)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\
&=-\pi
\end{align}$$

We can verify this by evaluating the volume integral directly as

$$\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec F\,dV=-\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \int_1^2 \frac{2\cos^2(\phi)}{r^4}\,r^2 \,\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=-\pi$$

as expected!

Comment: No I'm an engineering student at Istanbul Technical University. Sorry for my late response, but I think the number (2) mutiplied by the last integral is wrong. Thank you! you were really helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The number $2$ in the last integral comes from $\nabla \cdot \vec F=-\frac{2\cos^2(\phi)}{r^4}$.

Comment: Also, since you're new to the site, once you have enough reputation points you can up vote an answer too.  -Mark